# Best way to assign Table Column Width using th, td, col

Tags: html, html-table, width, column-width

What is the best way to assign a column width using the following: `<col>` `<th>` `<td>`?

What are the pros and cons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign your widths via css to <col> tags using class names for each such as .col-1, .col-2, .col-3, etc.

It's much easier to target those selectors than using, say, td:nth-child(n) or having to give class names for every td.  Your code will parse faster and be much cleaner too.

Comment: widths in <col> parse faster? do they still process the attribute cell by cell?

Comment: @agentprovocateur I just ran a performance test using col styling vs td styling (both tests used class selectors, not element selectors).  col styling was way more efficient than td styling.  td styling took 1.6x as long to render.  On a 100x100 table the average col-styled rendering speed was 97.76ms; the average td-styled rendering speed was 155.94ms.

Comment: BTW @agentprovocateur I used css styling for both tests.  You should never use width attributes in your HTML.  They are invalid in HTML5 (besides being bad form anyway).

Comment: oh, gotcha. i misunderstood.

Answer (score 1):

The most important thing to understand about html5 is the separation of content from markup. The column width in a table is markup, not content, so the tag used is irrelevant, you should use a CSS selector regardless. With that beings said, I think if your table already includes a col tag you should apply the style to it.

Comment: so you would suggest that I use class names, whereas haltersweb suggests otherwise for reasons of speed and readability?

Comment: @agentprovocateur you should always use class names, whether or not you choose to use col or td.  I suggest using col but you should assign class names to the col elements and style the widths in css. Never use the width attribute.